# angularjs table edit row

Tags: angularjs, button

1. I'm trying with Angularjs to make, when clicked a row in the table to let it appear an input to change the value of that row. Only now when I click the edit button the whole table shows.
2. The save and cancel button don't work anymore, because now also the save button cancels.`

```js
angular
    .module("form",["factories"])
    .controller("LocationFormCtrl", LocationFormCtrl);
    
function LocationFormCtrl(userFactory, carFactory, petFactory){
  var vm = this;
  vm.user = userFactory.getUser();
  vm.editorEnabled = false;

  vm.enableEditor = function(){
    vm.editorEnabled = true;
    vm.editName = vm.user.name;
    vm.editName = vm.users.name;
    vm.editMail = vm.user.mail;
    vm.editMail = vm.users.mail;

  };
  
  vm.save = function(){
    vm.user.name = vm.editName;
    vm.users.name = vm.editName;
    vm.user.mail = vm.editMail;
    vm.users.mail = vm.editMail;
    vm.disableEditor();
  };
  
  vm.disableEditor = function(){
    vm.editorEnabled = false;
  };

  vm.users = userFactory.getUsers();
}

var factories = angular.module("factories", []);

factories.factory('userFactory', function(){
  var factory = {
    getUser: getUser,
    getUsers: getUsers

  }

  return factory;

  function getUser(){
    var user = {
      name: "henk2",
      mail: 'aaa@gmail.com'
    }
    return user;
  }



  function getUsers(){
    var users = [
      {
        name: "Bert",
        mail: 'bert@gmail.com'
      },
      {
        name: "Giel",
        mail: 'giel@gmail.com'
      },
      {
        name: "Willem",
        mail: 'willem@gmail.com'
      }
    ];
    return users;
    selected: {}
  } 
});

factories.factory('carFactory', function(){
    var factory = {
      getCar : getCar
    }
  
  return factory;

  function getCar(){
    var car = {
      color: "black",
      maxSpeed: 200,
      name: "Audi r8 spyder"
    }
    return car;
  }
});

factories.factory("petFactory", function(){
  var factory = {
    getPet : getPet
  }

  return factory;

  function getPet(){
    var pet = {
      name: "vlekje",
      soort: "cat",
      age: 6
    }
    return pet;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="factories.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="form" ng-controller="LocationFormCtrl as vm">
    
<

    <table border="2">
        <tbody ng-submit="doneEditing">
            <tr ng-repeat="x in vm.users">
              <td>
                <input value="{{ x.name }}" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)" style="border: none;">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input value="{{ x.mail }}" ng-dblclick="editItem(item)" style= "border:none;">
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

 <table border="2">
      <tr ng-repeat="person in vm.users">
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="vm.editorEnabled">{{ person.name }}</div>
            <div ng-show="vm.editorEnabled">
              <input type="text"  value="{{ person.name }}"  />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="vm.editorEnabled">{{ person.mail }}</div>
            <div ng-show="vm.editorEnabled">
              <input type="text"  value="{{ person.mail }}" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="vm.editorEnabled">
              <div ng-click="vm.enableEditor()">Edit</div>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="vm.editorEnabled">
              <div ng-click="vm.save()" style="border-radius:50%; background-color:black; height:35px;width:35px;"  >
                <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white; margin-left:11px; margin-top:10px;"></i>
              </div>
              <div ng-click="vm.disableEditor()" style="border-radius:50%; background-color:black;height:35px; width:35px;">
                <i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white; margin-left:11px; margin-top:10px;"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $index inside your ng-repaeat in order to know which line have to be edited and which row have to saved.

Change your html to

```
<table border="2">
<tr ng-repeat="person in vm.users">
  <td>
    <div ng-hide="vm.editorEnabled[$index]">{{ person.name }}</div>
    <div ng-show="vm.editorEnabled[$index]">
      <input type="text" value="{{ person.name }}" ng-model="person.name" />
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div ng-hide="vm.editorEnabled[$index]">{{ person.mail }}</div>
    <div ng-show="vm.editorEnabled[$index]">
      <input type="text" value="{{ person.mail }}" ng-model="person.mail" />
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div ng-hide="vm.editorEnabled[$index]">
      <div ng-click="vm.enableEditor($index)">Edit</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="vm.editorEnabled[$index]">
      <div ng-click="vm.save($index,person.name,person.mail)" style="background-color:black; height:25px; width:45px;color: #fff;">
        save
      </div>
      <div ng-click="vm.disableEditor($index)" style="background-color:black;height:25px; width:45px;color: #fff;">
        cancel
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And your controller

```
vm.editorEnabled = [];

vm.enableEditor = function(index) {
    vm.editorEnabled[index] = true;
    vm.editName = vm.user.name;
    vm.editName = vm.users.name;
    vm.editMail = vm.user.mail;
    vm.editMail = vm.users.mail;
};

vm.save = function(index,editNameValue,editEmailValue) {
    vm.users[index].name = editNameValue;
    vm.users[index].mail = editEmailValue;
    vm.disableEditor(index);
};

vm.disableEditor = function(index) {
    vm.editorEnabled[index] = false;
};
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11235/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like below sample. Modify your code as per your need.

```js
angular
    .module("form",["factories"])
    .controller("LocationFormCtrl", LocationFormCtrl);
    
function LocationFormCtrl(userFactory, carFactory, petFactory){
  var vm = this;
  vm.user = userFactory.getUser();
 
  //vm.editorEnabled = false;
 vm.users = userFactory.getUsers();
  vm.enableEditor = function(person, index){   
   if(!vm.users[index].editorEnabled){
    vm.users[index].editorEnabled = true;
    }

  };
  
  vm.editItem = function(index){
  vm.users[index].editorEnabled = true;
  }
  
    vm.doneEditing = function(user, index){
    console.log(user);
  //vm.users[index].editorEnabled = false;
  }
  
  vm.save = function(person, index){
   console.log(person);
    vm.disableEditor(index);
  };
  
  vm.disableEditor = function(index){
  vm.users[index].editorEnabled = false;
  };

 
}

var factories = angular.module("factories", []);

factories.factory('userFactory', function(){
  var factory = {
    getUser: getUser,
    getUsers: getUsers

  }

  return factory;

  function getUser(){
    var user = {
      name: "henk2",
      mail: 'aaa@gmail.com'
    }
    return user;
  }



  function getUsers(){
    var users = [
      {
        name: "Bert",
        mail: 'bert@gmail.com'
      },
      {
        name: "Giel",
        mail: 'giel@gmail.com'
      },
      {
        name: "Willem",
        mail: 'willem@gmail.com'
      }
    ];
    return users;
    selected: {}
  } 
});

factories.factory('carFactory', function(){
    var factory = {
      getCar : getCar
    }
  
  return factory;

  function getCar(){
    var car = {
      color: "black",
      maxSpeed: 200,
      name: "Audi r8 spyder"
    }
    return car;
  }
});

factories.factory("petFactory", function(){
  var factory = {
    getPet : getPet
  }

  return factory;

  function getPet(){
    var pet = {
      name: "vlekje",
      soort: "cat",
      age: 6
    }
    return pet;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="factories.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="form" ng-controller="LocationFormCtrl as vm">  


    <table border="2">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in vm.users">
             <form ng-submit="vm.doneEditing(x,$index)" novalidate name="form"> <td ng-dblclick="editorEnabled = !editorEnabled">
                <input ng-disabled="!editorEnabled" ng-model="x.name" style="border: none;">
              </td>
              <td ng-dblclick="mailEnabled = !mailEnabled">
                <input ng-disabled="!mailEnabled" ng-model="x.mail" ng-dblclick="vm.editItem($index)" style= "border:none;">
              </td>
              <td><input ng-click="vm.doneEditing(x,$index);editorEnabled =false;mailEnabled =false;" type="submit" class="btn btn-out" value="Save" /></td>
              </form>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

 <table border="2">
      <tr ng-repeat="person in vm.users">
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="person.editorEnabled">{{ person.name }}</div>
            <div ng-show="person.editorEnabled">
              <input type="text" ng-model="person.name"  />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="person.editorEnabled">{{ person.mail }}</div>
            <div ng-show="person.editorEnabled">
              <input type="text" ng-model="person.mail" />
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div ng-hide="person.editorEnabled">
              <div ng-click="vm.enableEditor(person, $index)">Edit</div>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="person.editorEnabled">
              <div ng-click="vm.save(person, $index)" style="border-radius:50%; background-color:black; height:35px;width:35px;"  >
                <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white; margin-left:11px; margin-top:10px;"></i>
              </div>
              <div ng-click="vm.disableEditor($index)" style="border-radius:50%; background-color:black;height:35px; width:35px;">
                <i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white; margin-left:11px; margin-top:10px;"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```